# how to integrate servlet/jsp page in android application?

Tags: android, jsp, servlets, webview

I want to store & retrieve the data from android web application to MySQL through jsp/servlet.

is it possible ? how : any other way to do this things.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use JSP/SERVLET as a middle layer, then send HTTP requests from your Android application to it.

To retrive data:

At JSP/SERVLET [Server] side code to:

- connect to the database
- run an SQL query, query may contain WHERE block depending on data from POST/GET
  values

At Android [Client] side code:

- use a HttpPost for sending the parameter value
- convert response to string
- parse the data and use it as you want.

Same way you can add new entries in database.

For reference look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) or you can also use [HTTPConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpConnection.html).